# Evaluate if a control is of a parent type at runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, runtime

Is there a way to get code like this print "Test";

```
DecendedTextBox myControl = new DecendedTextbox();

if (myControl is "TextBox")
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

The point here is that I need to see if myControl inherits from a type that I don't have a reference to at Compile Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a reference to the type, you can do this:

```
DecendedTextBox myControl = new DecendedTextbox();

if (myControl.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

If you want to know the full type name, including namespace, you can use `GetType().FullName`

As far as checking to see if it inherits from the type, something like this:

```
DecendedTextBox myControl = new DecendedTextbox();
Type typeToCheck = Type.GetType("TextBox");
if (myControl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeToCheck))
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Note that [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx#Y0) takes an [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), so you'll need to know the full type name.

Comment: But that will not be true.  myControl.GetType().Name returns "DecendedTextbox".

Answer (score 1):

If you need to avoid pulling the `Type` reference out via reflection, then you can crawl up the inheritance tree:

```
public static bool IsTypeSubclassOf(Type subclass, string baseClassFullName)
{
    while (subclass != typeof(object))
    {
        if (subclass.FullName == baseClassFullName)
            return true;
        else
            subclass = subclass.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```